# Update Customer JWT Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, api

I am using JWT to make call threw the woocommerce api.

I created a kind of bot which is an admin user which I connect through JWT api to get a token.

With the token at the moment I am doing calls to create customers, orders. Getting products and everything is working fine. I am trying to implement a new call to update a customer and I have `woocommerce_rest_cannot_edit` . The user I am making the call with is admin and have an aop rest key related to him granting access on read and write. Not sure this api key is useful.

If I am trying to make a call with this api key I have an error from JWT `jwt_auth_bad_auth_header`

Answer (score 1):

The user you are using to update an user has to be network admin

This was my issue